# React Typescript: How to handle Formik File Upload?

Tags: typescript, formik, react-tsx, formik-material-ui

I am using Formik on React Typescript to handle my Student Profile form. This form is supposed to handle resume and transcript file upload. I noticed that everything worked great until I tested my form in Chrome and saw in the console log that the value of the input node for the resume and transcript files were being set to C:\fakepath{Original File Name}.

```
import React from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';

import useApi from 'hooks/useApi';
import useSnack from 'hooks/useSnack';
import Loader from 'Components/Loader';
import { TextFormField } from 'Components/TextFormField';
import { SelectFormField } from 'Components/SelectFormField';
import Button from 'Components/Button';
import {
    classStandingTypes,
    createStudentProfile,
} from 'Domains/Student/api/api';

import {
    departments,
} from 'sharedData'

export interface IStudentProfileForm {
    firstName: string; 
    middleName: string; 
    lastName: string; 
    departmentId: string;
    sid: number; 
    classStanding: string; 
    email: string; 
    biography: string;
    resume: string;
    transcript: string;
};

const formInitialValues: IStudentProfileForm = {
    firstName: '',
    middleName: '', 
    lastName: '', 
    departmentId: '',
    sid: 0, 
    classStanding: '',
    email: '',
    biography: '',
    resume: '',
    transcript: '',  
};

const formSchema = yup.object({
    firstName: yup.string().required('First name is required'),
    lastName: yup.string().required('Last name is required'),
    departmentId: yup.string().required('Department is required'),
    sid: yup.string().required('Student ID is is required'),
    classStanding: yup.string().required("Class standing is required"),
    email: yup.string().required('Email is required').email('Please enter valid email'),
    biography: yup.string().required("Biography is required")
});
    
function StudentProfileForm() {
    const [studentProfile, setStudentProfile] = React.useState<IStudentProfileForm>(formInitialValues);
    const request = React.useCallback(() => createStudentProfile(studentProfile), [studentProfile]);
    const [snack] = useSnack();
    const [sendRequest, isLoading] = useApi(request, {
        onSuccess: () => {
            snack('Student profile successfully created!', 'success');
        },
    });
    return (
        <Paper style={{ padding: 50 }}>
            <Formik
                validationSchema={formSchema}
                initialValues={formInitialValues}
                onSubmit={(formValues, actions) => 
                    {
                    console.log(formValues);
                    setStudentProfile(formValues);
                    sendRequest();
                    actions.resetForm({
                        values: { ...formInitialValues },
                    });
                }}
            >
                {() => (
                    <Form>
                        <Grid container spacing={3} alignContent='center'>
                            <Grid item container justify='flex-start'>
                                <Typography variant='h4'>Create Student Profile</Typography>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item container spacing={5}>
                                <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
                                    <Field
                                        name='firstName'
                                        label='First Name'
                                        component={TextFormField}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
                                    <Field
                                        name='middleName'
                                        label='Middle Name'
                                        component={TextFormField}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
                                    <Field
                                        name='lastName'
                                        label='Last Name'
                                        component={TextFormField}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
                                    <Field
                                        name='departmentId'
                                        label='Department'
                                        options={departments}
                                        component={SelectFormField}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
                                    <Field
                                        name='classStanding'
                                        label='Class Standing'
                                        options={classStandingTypes}
                                        component={SelectFormField}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
                                    <Field
                                        name='sid'
                                        label='SID'
                                        type = 'number'
                                        component={TextFormField}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
                                    <Field
                                        name='email'
                                        label='Email'
                                        component={TextFormField}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
                                    <Field
                                        name='resume'
                                        label='Resume'
                                        type='file'
                                        InputLabelProps={{
                                            shrink: true,
                                        }}
                                        component={TextFormField}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
                                    <Field
                                        name='transcript'
                                        label='Transcript'
                                        type='file'
                                        InputLabelProps={{
                                            shrink: true,
                                        }}
                                        component={TextFormField}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item md={12} xs={12}>
                                    <Field
                                        name='biography'
                                        label='Biography'
                                        multiline
                                        component={TextFormField}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid container item xs={12}>
                                <Button type='submit' isLoading={isLoading}>
                                    Submit
                                    {isLoading && <Loader size={20} />}
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </Paper>
    );
}

export default StudentProfileForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Formik doesnot support fileupload by default, But you can try the following

```
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" onChange={(event) =>{ 
      formik.setFieldValue("file", event.currentTarget.files[0]);
}} />
```

And this will work like a charm :)